# Swagger, how to generate python-flask server with oneOf used in schemas (getting weird result)?

Tags: python, flask, swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen

I have a following schema:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  description: test
  version: 1.0.0
  title: test
components:
  schemas:
    superObject:
      type: object
      properties:
        theObject:
          oneOf:
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/simpleObject'
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/complexObject'
      discriminator:
        propertyName: objectType

    simpleObject:
      type: object
      required:
        - objectType
      properties:
        objectType:
          type: string

    complexObject:
      type: object
      required:
        - objectType
      properties:
        objectType:
          type: string
```

What I want to do is generate a server and the corresponding models in `python-flask` using Swagger (3, so I can use OpenAPI 3 and make use of the `oneOf` element. I want 3 objects, in which the `superObject` can be validated with one of `simpleObject` or `complexObject`.

Using `swagger-codegen` with version `3.0.42`, I ran `swagger-codegen generate -i ./test.yaml -l python-flask -o ./` on the model. What I  get however, isn't what I expected. I see the models `simple_object.py`, `complex_object.py`, and `super_object.py`, but I also get a `one_ofsuper_object_the_object.py`, which to me is an indication that I messed up somewhere.

The `one_ofsuper_object_the_object.py` that is generated:

```
class OneOfsuperObjectTheObject(Model):
    """NOTE: This class is auto generated by the swagger code generator program.

    Do not edit the class manually.
    """
    def __init__(self):  # noqa: E501
        """OneOfsuperObjectTheObject - a model defined in Swagger

        """
        self.swagger_types = {
        }

        self.attribute_map = {
        }

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, dikt) -> 'OneOfsuperObjectTheObject':
        """Returns the dict as a model

        :param dikt: A dict.
        :type: dict
        :return: The OneOfsuperObjectTheObject of this OneOfsuperObjectTheObject.  # noqa: E501
        :rtype: OneOfsuperObjectTheObject
        """
        return util.deserialize_model(dikt, cls)
```

This is the generated `super_object.py`

```
class SuperObject(Model):
    """NOTE: This class is auto generated by the swagger code generator program.

    Do not edit the class manually.
    """
    def __init__(self, the_object: OneOfsuperObjectTheObject=None):  # noqa: E501
        """SuperObject - a model defined in Swagger

        :param the_object: The the_object of this SuperObject.  # noqa: E501
        :type the_object: OneOfsuperObjectTheObject
        """
        self.swagger_types = {
            'the_object': OneOfsuperObjectTheObject
        }

        self.attribute_map = {
            'the_object': 'theObject'
        }
        self._the_object = the_object

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, dikt) -> 'SuperObject':
        """Returns the dict as a model

        :param dikt: A dict.
        :type: dict
        :return: The superObject of this SuperObject.  # noqa: E501
        :rtype: SuperObject
        """
        return util.deserialize_model(dikt, cls)

    @property
    def the_object(self) -> OneOfsuperObjectTheObject:
        """Gets the the_object of this SuperObject.


        :return: The the_object of this SuperObject.
        :rtype: OneOfsuperObjectTheObject
        """
        return self._the_object

    @the_object.setter
    def the_object(self, the_object: OneOfsuperObjectTheObject):
        """Sets the the_object of this SuperObject.


        :param the_object: The the_object of this SuperObject.
        :type the_object: OneOfsuperObjectTheObject
        """

        self._the_object = the_object
```

My understanding is that `oneOf` is only in swagger 3 and open api 3, and it looks like I'm using both. If I can get insight into what I did wrong, that would be great.